# I accepted two law school admission offers with two different start dates. Do I have to tell the latter that I've already taken classes at the former?

Tags: united-states, law

I applied simultaneously to several law schools with start dates in January 2022 and September 2022. I received and accepted multiple offers and paid for all the seats I accepted.

I've now finished my first semester at the school with the January start. I did mediocre on my first semester finals. I am not on academic probation or academically dismissed. But I don't want a 2.3 GPA, and this school is expensive (I lost my scholarship due to my GPA). After finding the structural issues in my test taking, I am hoping I will do better if I could get a fresh start. So, I am planning to leave my current program and start from the beginning at one of the schools with the September 2022 start date.

My new program will not know that I started and left a program somewhere else. Do I have to tell them? I do not want to transfer the grades, so from my side, there is no need to mention it. I did not lie on my application. I have researched this and cannot find any discussion about this scenario, only about transfer applications. Can I just go for it?

Comment: Interesting question, but you should be aware that we have very few users who are familiar with law school in the US (and I seriously doubt we have any who are law school administration and thus could tell you authoritatively how this sort of thing would be handled if you were found out).

Comment: At US R1 math program. Aware that Law Schools (as at my univ) are often entities-unto-themselves, playing by their own rules. But, if you had asked our (math) dept for a year's deferral, and if it were granted (which might or might not be), then we'd _not_ ask for a complete reapplication... A reapplication _would_ require complete info about everything, and if you lied or omitted things we'd consider it fraud (of some degree of severity). So it's conceivable that you have arranged, or could arrange, just restarting, rather than transferring... but don't lie. :)

Comment: I'm still trying to get my head around this timeline. Did you apply to both schools in ~September and accept both offers in ~December? It's hard to imagine there is a ~10 month gap between reserving your spot and starting (unless you arranged for a deferral, which you do not mention). Or did you submit your application for September on ~December 1st and accept the offer for January on ~December 2nd?

Comment: Can you clarify why you perceive that you have anything to hide? You were accepted into the program, paid the tuition and have a secured spot. In what way do you imagine that them knowing about you transferring in from another program could negatively affect your status in the program?

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to engage in the practice of law, your conduct should be exemplary. In fact, there is often a morality clause to admission to the bar.

Put yourself in the position of the second school. Will they possibly feel deceived by you not telling? For example, did they ask in the admissions process about previous studies? If yes, you definitely should tell your new school.

Assume an alternative scenario, where you leave your current school after the semester (disgusted with your performance), work in another job for a couple of years, and then go to the new law school. Would that have made any difference?

With other words, your decision should focus on whether you have an explicit or implicit duty to advise your new school. If you were to breach a duty, your future career might be in jeopardy.

Answer (score 0):

While your behavior doesn't seem especially honorable, I'd guess that you don't have to tell the other school what you have been doing, as long as you don't lie when asked questions.

Your admittance to that program, I assume, wasn't contingent on what you might do or not do in the interim. You could have been vacationing in the south of France, or anything. They probably didn't anticipate that your situation could arise and so didn't try to prevent it.

It would be different, though, if they did require you to keep them informed of what you were doing, especially academic programs, in the time before starting. In such a case, you need to tell them and likely provide transcripts. To fail in this would be an ethical lapse.

It does all seem a bit "slippery" though, and feeds into the general distrust of lawyers.

Accepting more than one offer was problematic if you thereby denied a slot to another potential student. Law school admissions tend to be a bit limited, I'd suppose.

Comment: Don't know about law schools, but my Ph.D. application asked for *all* transcripts, with a note that it was "a continuing obligation."  They did want to know what I was doing in the interim, at least with respect to education.

Comment: @BobBrown, my experience was different, but honesty is required whatever the constraints.